# Are there examples of spring-mass-damper system that exhibit increasing growth in an unstable way

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, dynamics, modeling

Simply, are there examples of spring-mass-damper systems that exhibit unbounded behavior or at least increasing behavior for a period of time. I am trying to do some vibrations research, but I am quite out of practice with it.

Comment: Unbounded? No. For that, you must have something that puts more energy into the system than the bounded input. Increasing? Yes, any high-Q resonator (i.e. just spring-mass with little or no damping). A small amplitude excitation at the resonant frequency, will have output of "increasing" amplitude - possibly until it hits some mechanical limit.

Comment: A bi-stable spring. Consider a cone spring being pressed until it inverts and "pops" in the opposite direction..